# Open a web browser from push notification without launching the application?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver

My application is running in the background and I send a push notification through postman using the payload below.

Now when I send this, I get the notification and when I tap it, it launches my application's Main Activity. But I want to launch the web browser which opens the link that I send in the notification body. How to do this?? Can somebody please help.

```
{
 "to" : "MY_TOKEN",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#click",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2",
     "click_action" : "OPEN_WEB"
 }
}
```

Comment: What `PendingIntent` do you pass to the `Notification` when you build it?

Comment: I need help in how to do this? @MidasLefko